# How to use the same variable more than one time in function concat() MySql

Tags: mysql

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `tr_tblEmployee_Update` BEFORE UPDATE ON `tblEmployee` FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN

 DECLARE id int; DECLARE OldGender varchar(10); DECLARE NewGender varchar(10); DECLARE NewName varchar(50); DECLARE OldName varchar(50);
 DECLARE OldSalary int; DECLARE NewSalary int; DECLARE OldID_Dep int; DECLARE NewId_Dep int;
 DECLARE AuditString varchar(300);

    SET id = ID_Employee; SET NewGender = Gender; SET NewName = Name; SET NewSalary = Salary; SET NewID_Dep = ID_Dep;
    SET OldGender = Gender; SET OldName = Name; SET OldSalary = Salary; SET OldID_Dep = ID_Dep;

    SET AuditString = concat('Employee with id = ',id,' changed: ')
    IF(OldName<>NewName)
        SET AuditString = concat(AuditString, 'Name from ',OldName,' to ',NewName);
    IF(OldGender<>NewGender)
        SET AuditString = concat(AuditString, ' Gender from ',OldGender,' to ',NewGender);
    IF(OldSalary<>NewSalary)
        SET AuditString = concat(AuditString, ' Salary from ',OldName,' to ',NewName);
    IF(OldDep<>NewDep)
        SET AuditString = concat(AuditString, ' Department from ',OldName,' to ',NewName);

    INSERT INTO tblemployeeaudit(AuditData) VALUES(AuditString);
END
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Hello, i want to use the concat function with the same variable (AuditString) multiple times, but i get an error every time i try to do it.

> Error - #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
>   that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax
>   to use near 'IF(OldName!=NewName)
>           SET AuditString = concat(AuditString, 'Name from ',Ol'... at line 12

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server? (Don't tag products not involved.)

Comment: post the error message as well

Comment: I'm using MySql, sorry my first time posting here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing `;` semicolon before  the line `IF(OldName<>NewName)`

As well, Your `IF` syntax looks incorrect to me. It should rather be

```
IF(OldName<>NewName) THEN
    SET AuditString = concat(AuditString, 'Name from ',OldName,' to ',NewName);
END IF;
```

Comment: Thanks you very much, i was trying it for 1 hour and didn't notice the semicolon that was missing.

Answer (score 0):

This is the final solution, in case anyone else is having the same problem as me.

DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `tr_tblEmployee_Update` BEFORE UPDATE ON `tblEmployee` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

DECLARE id int; DECLARE OldGender varchar(10); DECLARE NewGender varchar(10); DECLARE NewName varchar(50); DECLARE OldName varchar(50);
 DECLARE OldSalary int; DECLARE NewSalary int; DECLARE OldID_Dep int; DECLARE NewId_Dep int;
 DECLARE AuditString varchar(300);

```
SET id = OLD.ID_Employee; SET NewGender = NEW.Gender; SET NewName = NEW.NAME; SET NewSalary = NEW.Salary;
SET OldGender = OLD.Gender; SET OldName = OLD.NAME; SET OldSalary = OLD.Salary;

SET AuditString = concat('Employee with id = ',id,' changed: ');
IF(OldName<>NewName) THEN
    SET AuditString = concat(AuditString, 'Name from ',OldName,' to ',NewName);
END IF;
IF(OldGender<>NewGender) THEN
    SET AuditString = concat(AuditString, ' Gender from ',OldGender,' to ',NewGender);
END IF;
IF(OldSalary<>NewSalary) THEN
    SET AuditString = concat(AuditString, ' Salary from ',OldSalary,' to ',NewSalary);
END IF;    
INSERT INTO tblemployeeaudit(AuditData) VALUES(AuditString);
```

END